# css fixed elements issue on "hand holding-page" effect

Tags: css, positioning, fixed

I think images are better than words:
[image]

I want to build a page with a fake effect hand "holding" my webpage.So while the page scrolls the hand stay on the bottom-left corner of the browser.

I think a "fixed" position for my "hand" is what I would need so I have this css:

```
.class-applied-to-my-hand-image{
position:fixed;
bottom:0;
    left:0;
}
```

and my html:

```
[..]
<body>
 <img src="fingers.png" class="class-applied-to-my-hand-image"/>
 <div class="scrolling-page">
  [..] 
 </div>
<body>
```

This is fine unless I decide to zoom the page (ctrl++) cause the image continue to follow its css rule and stay on the bottom-left corner of the browser.This cause the "fingers" to overlap my articles.

What do I need here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe using 3 divs, absolute positioning for the scrolling page and fixed positioning for the fingers.

This is the CSS:

```
      <style type="text/css" media="screen">
        /* Reset (Eric Meyer) v2.0 | 20110126 */
        ....
        /* Fingers css rules */
        div#wrapper{position:relative;}
        div#fingers{position:fixed;bottom:0;left:0;width:25%;z-index:99;}
        div#fingers img{max-width:100%;min-width:100%;}
        div#scrolling_page{position:absolute;top:0;left:15%;width:50%;margin:0px auto;border: 1px solid #999;z-index:98;padding:20px;}
      </style>
```

And this is the HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
      <div id="fingers">
        <img src="fingers.png" alt="fingers"/>
      </div>
      <div id="scrolling_page">
      <!-- a lot of text paragraphs here -->
      <p>...</p>
      </div>
</div>
```

I need to tweak a little the fingers image, removing some white background and changing it to png in order to have transparency.
You can see the source code and try zooming the page [here](http://microspino.com/hand_zoom.html)

**NOTE**

I'm sorry but I haven't had the time to cross-browser test the code. I strongly suggest you to do some test before to go public.

Comment: in your example scrolling_page div and the image are not overlapping.How would you make the effect "hand-back/paper-front" with the four fingers hidden back? What for the left grey border of the scrolling-page div behind the thumb?thanks

Comment: @luca Updated code starting from your comment (BTW l'url del tuo sito è splendida).

Comment: just looking at the code it looks like with absolute positioning "fingers" div We won't have 'em fixed in the bottom-left of the screen..(grazie ma il merito va ai nostri politici soprattutto!per lo spunto.Diciamo.)

Comment: @luca Now is bottom-left (sorry I haven't see it before) and scrolls with fixed fingers. The image need some improvement I'm not good at photoshop ;)